# JUnit: Check that a collection only contains objects of a certain type

Tags: collections, types, junit

Say I have a method that returns a collection of `Animal`s. In one case I want to check that this method contains exactly 7 `Dog`s. Checking the number isn't a problem, but how would you check that all the animals are instances of `Dog`?

I suppose I could loop over the collection, but is there a more JUnity of saying "assert that this collection contains only objects which are dogs"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit's assertion methods don't cater for something this specific. Your best bet is to create a general helper function like so:

```
public static void assertTypeForAll(Collection<?> c, Class<?> type) {
    for (Object o : c) {
        Assert.assertTrue("Object " + o + " should be a subclass of " + type, type.isInstance(o));
    }
}
```

Then you can write:

```
assertTypeForAll(animals, Dog.class);
```

Comment: Deal. Was hoping there was something like in NUnit, http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.5

Answer (score 1):

I got great results when I started writing unit tests in Groovy.  No risk to the production code, but a great reduction in the size of the unit test code:

```
assert animals.size == 7 && animals.every { it instanceof Dog }
```

The only problem is that after a few days, you want to use Groovy for the production code too.